# While loops duplicating the results

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have 2 rows in the table and when I do a while loop to fetch it in the php it duplicates the results 5 times. As you can see it creates a table and there are just 2 rows it seems strange to duplicate the results.. I even found an answered here on StackOverflow saying to add "DISTINCT" on the query and it doesnt work on mine...

```
    <?php
// A sessão precisa ser iniciada em cada página diferente
$id=null;
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['UsuarioID']))
{
    $id = $_SESSION['UsuarioID'];
}
?>
    <head>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.iconj.com/ico/7/5/75jqn04zq9.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <title>Verificar estado</title></head>
    <body>
    </div><?php
    //Tentativa de estabelecer uma ligação à BD
    $connection = new mysqli('***', '***', '****', '****');

    //Verificar se a ligação foi estabelecida com sucesso
    if (mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
        echo "</h2>Erro no acesso à base de dados.</h2>" . mysqli_connect_error(); 
        exit();
        } 


    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT id_user, id_ficha, avaria, observacoes, estado, id FROM fichas, usuarios WHERE id_user = " . $id.";";
    //Executar a Query! 
    $result = $connection->query($sql);
    echo "<div id='listanomes'>User ID - ID Ficha - Avaria</div>";
    ?>
    <div id="lista">
    <div class="estados">
    <?php
    while ($userproduto = $result->fetch_object()) {
        echo '<table border="1">';
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $userproduto->id_user . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $userproduto->id_ficha . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $userproduto->avaria . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $userproduto->observacoes . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $userproduto->estado . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
    } 

        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    //Termina o script

        echo '<div class="foot">';
        echo '<p>Copyright © 2013 - Todos os direitos reservados - <a href="mailto:numica@numica.pt">Númica</a></p>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</body>';
        echo '</html>';
    exit();
    ?>
```

Comment: When you run the query from the command line how many results do you get/

Comment: You are querying two tables `fichas` and `usarios`. How may rows are in each table?

Comment: 5 on the table "usuarios", I deleted some fields from the query and it works now. sorry for the trouble!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the join statement to join your 2 tables, otherwise SQL do a cartesian product.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_user, id_ficha, avaria, observacoes, estado, id FROM fichas, usuarios WHERE id_user = $id AND fichas.id = usarios.id_fichas
```

Comment: tried out ur solution but it keeps duplicating :s I did this: "SELECT DISTINCT avaria, observacoes, estado FROM fichas WHERE id_user = " . $id.";";" and it works now :D

Comment: it work because you delete some row in your usuarios table, but if you put more than 1 row in this table you will have the same issue... you have to link the usarios unique key with the related key in fichas table.

Comment: No, since in my new query I don't import the table "usuarios" and since the table "fichas" has user_id and "usuarios" was only to import the "id" and they are the same, it really works